# Unable to extract the text of a simple selector using Cheerio

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I'm trying to extract the text corresponding to the description of a Chrome extension from its page (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/earth-view-from-google-ea/bhloflhklmhfpedakmangadcdofhnnoh) using cheerio (see code snippet below), to no avail.
As you can see I tried 3 different easy selectors, but all of them yield an empty string.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/earth-view-from-google-ea/bhloflhklmhfpedakmangadcdofhnnoh',
     function (error, response, html) {
         if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                     var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                     console.log ( $('div.C-b-p-j-D.Ka-Ia-j.C-b-p-j-D-gi').text() )
                     console.log( $("div[itemprop='description']").text())
                     console.log ( $("div.C-b-p-j-Pb").text() )
         }});
```

The first selector works flawlessly from DevTools console, though:

[image]

Any hint will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. The data is in the static response, so Cheerio should be able to find it. You can see it works with JSDOM:

```js
const {JSDOM} = require("jsdom"); // 20.0.0

const url = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/earth-view-from-google-ea/bhloflhklmhfpedakmangadcdofhnnoh";
JSDOM.fromURL(url).then(({window: {document}}) => {
  const selector = ".C-b-p-j-D.Ka-Ia-j.C-b-p-j-D-gi";
  console.log(document.querySelector(selector).textContent);
});
```

And with Python/BeautifulSoup:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/earth-view-from-google-ea/bhloflhklmhfpedakmangadcdofhnnoh"
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

print(soup.select_one('meta[property="og:description"]')["content"])
print("-" * 50)
print(soup.select_one("[itemprop='description']").text)
print("-" * 50)
print(soup.select_one('.C-b-p-j-D.Ka-Ia-j.C-b-p-j-D-gi').text)
```

After minimizing the problem, it boils down to this:

```js
const {load} = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <noscript>
    <p>foo</p>
  </noscript>
</body>
</html>`;

console.dir(load(html)("p").text()); // => ''
console.dir(load(html, {scriptingEnabled: false})("p").text()); // => 'foo'
console.dir(load(html, {xml: true})("p").text()); // => 'foo'
```

You can see that the `<noscript>` tag is the culprit. Adding one of two options, `scriptingEnabled: false` or `xml: true` (or deprecated `xmlMode`) allows Cheerio to parse the contents of `<noscript>`. See [Cheerio issue #1105](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/1105) for details.

At a glance, it's unclear to me which is preferable, but [this comment](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/1105#issuecomment-625574901) indicates that `xmlMode` has side effects and may cause pages to fail to parse, so I'll go with `scriptingEnabled` for now.

Back to your code. I used `fetch` which is native in recent Node versions, but it's a cosmetic change. You can use any request library.

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/earth-view-from-google-ea/bhloflhklmhfpedakmangadcdofhnnoh";

fetch(url)
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.status);
    }

    return response.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html, {scriptingEnabled: false});
    console.log($("div.C-b-p-j-D.Ka-Ia-j.C-b-p-j-D-gi").text());
    console.log($('div[itemprop="description"]').text());
    console.log($("div.C-b-p-j-Pb").text());
  });
```

By the way, some of the data is available in a tag in the header:

```html
<meta property="og:description" content="Experience a beautiful image from Google Earth every time you open a new tab.">
```

Since this isn't inside a `<noscript>`, you can select it without the special options:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(html); // nothing special
console.log($('meta[property="og:description"]').attr("content"));
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the detailed explanation and the different alternatives exposed. I learned a lot from this answer.